# .htaccess allow all sorts of content types

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, content-type

I have a .htaccess in my public_html folder which only allows specific content types, that part looks like this:

```
# BAD Content Type ^
# Denies any POST request with a content type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded|multipart/form-data
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} !^(application/x-www-form-urlencoded|multipart/form-data.*(boundary.*)?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]
```

I have a subdomain, which should allow all sorts of content types (because of external post methods).
So I'd like to know how I can tell .htaccess that my subdomain should not be blocked.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another `RewriteCond` using `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} !^(application/x-www-form-urlencoded|multipart/form-data.*(boundary.*)?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]
```